# Change a react component dom parent without unmounting/resetting it

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that is meant to do a query to a server and display a list of results.

I would like to change the layout of my dom depending on some variable. My issue is that when I change the layout, the component is reset and the query is done once again. I would like to be able to move this component in the dom without resetting it, so the shown result stays the same without doing the query again.

In this case, I would like `this.mainSNL()` to return the same component without resetting it when it is displayed directly or as a part of `this.linkTabs()` (`this.mainSNL()` is called both in the `render()` and `this.linkTabs()` functions):

```
render()
{
    return (
        <div>
            {this.userInputElement()}

            <div className="main_display_area">
                {
                    this.state.linkingNote != undefined ?
                        this.linkTabs()
                        :
                        this.mainSNL()
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

mainSNL()
{
    return (
        <StreamedNoteList
            ref={(streamedList) => { this.mainSNLElement = streamedList; } }
            /* long list of props*/
        />
    )
}

linkTabs()
{
    if(this.state.linkingNote == undefined)
        return null;

    return (
        <div>
            <ul id='note_display_tabs' className="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" className="active">
                    <a href="#search_note_tab" aria-controls="search_note_tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Create Link</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" >
                    <a href="#view_links_tab" aria-controls="view_links_tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">View Links</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div className="link_tabs tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-pane fade in active" id="search_note_tab">{this.mainSNL()}</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" className="tab-pane fade" id="view_links_tab">{this.viewLinksSNL()}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do the query load on `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`? This will only run once.

Comment: I actually do the query every time a `searchQuery` props is changed, not only when the component in mounted. Still, this `searchQuery` value is  the same in this case, no matter if the component is created at the "root" of my div or inside the `linkTabs()` function.
I have a safety that checks what was the last `searchQuery` and not perform the query again if it's the same but simply shows the previous results. But because the component seems to be reset, not only the query is done again, but even the results of the previous query (that should be saved) disappear.

Comment: I tried the `componentDidMount` anyway, and it is re-run each time I change the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by saving the state of the component in the parent and "importing" within the component constructor function.

```
render()
{
    if(this.mainSNLElement != null)
    {
      this.savedMainState = this.mainSNLElement.state;
    }

    ...
}

mainSNL()
{
    return (
        <StreamedNoteList
            ref={(streamedList) => { this.mainSNLElement = streamedList; } }
            importState={this.savedMainState}
            /* long list of props*/
        />
    )
}

linkTabs() { ... }
```

This question didn't give me any solution but it had some insight on what was causing the issue:
https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/maintaining-state-of-wrapped-re-parented-components/4091

React doc on why this was happening: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html